# python error: request isn't defined

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, urldecode

I am trying to learn how to automatically fetch urls from a page. In the following code I am trying to get the port co-ordinates of the webpage from different links:

```
import urllib.request
import re


a = input("What country is your port in?: ")
b = input("What is the name of the port?: ")

url = "http://ports.com/"

totalurl = "http://ports.com/" + a + "/" + b + "/"
htmlfile = request.urlopen(url)
htmltext = htmlfile.read()
regex = '<span class="small'+ a + "/" + b + "/" '">...</span>'
pattern = re.compile(regex)

with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
    html = response.read().decode()

num = re.findall(pattern, html)
print(num)


This is the error message I receive:
    What country is your port in?: greece
    What is the name of the port?: port-of-eleusis
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/kieronblemings/Desktop/PROGRAMS PYTHON/ports extraction.py", line 13, in <module>
        htmlfile = request.urlopen(url)
    NameError: name 'request' is not defined
```

Comment: try `from urllib import request` ?

Comment: or on the line where you use request, say `urllib.request.urlopen(url)` instead.

Comment: Also, since you're using python3? you can just import `requests` directly. (Nvm, requests seems to be something else, which you can also use if you're interested)

Comment: ...or `import urllib.request as request`

Comment: Ive tried both ideas, still coming up with an errors. @Andersson tried your idea and now it comes up with: 'urllib' is not defined

Comment: so it seems that `urllib` is not installed yet. check [this link](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-install-urllib-and-urllib2-for-Python-3-3-2)

Comment: Just change 7th line to `htmlfile = urllib.request.urlopen(url)`

Comment: Now its not coming up with any errors but is now printing "[ ]" and nothing else or inside them? @Andersson

Comment: and ive tried that idea but the output is still "[ ]". @t.m.adam

Comment: Yes, this pattern won't match anything useful. What are you trying to scrape? And why don't you use `bs4`?

Comment: I'm trying to scrape co-ordinates from a website called [link](http://ports.com), I need a user to enter the country name and port name and the program will output the co-ordinates of the port. @t.m.adam

Comment: Then your pattern should be something like `regex = '<strong>Coordinates:</strong>(.*?)</span>'`, and you should search in `totalurl`.